# deleting multiple items at a time in local database in swift4.2

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I am using a third party library as internal db.it is SharkORM.By using this am able to delete a selected one item at a time ,but my requirement is I need to delete multiple selected items in a collection view.Can anyone help me to do this would be great thanks in advance.and my folder structure is a list of folders ,each folder will be having a collection of imagefiles and list of pdf files.here I want to delete selected image files at a time.

```
 class func DeleteSelectedDocuments(selectedIndexes: [Int],fileId:String){
            File.query()
            .where(withFormat: "parentIdentifier = %@", withParameters: selectedIndexes)
            .fetch()
            .removeAll()
    }
```

this is the query which I have written to delete selected items of collection view in a folder,but the items are not removing from db.

Answer (score 1):

As Mentioned in document:

> **Removing objects**
>
> To remove an object from Shark you simply call
> **remove()** on this object, this will delete it form the data store and
> sterilise it to ensure it cannot be accidentally written back at a
> later date. To optimise the **bulk removal** of objects, **a query can be
> combined with a call to removeAll() on the result set to delete many
> objects at once**.

Reference: https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Parth and here is a snippet that might help you

```
Employee.query()
.whereWithFormat("your criteria...", parameters: YOUR_PARAMS)
.fetch()
.removeAll()
```

Comment: Here in the parameters array of selected indexes of collection view or selected items array ,which one should be there

Comment: you can pass your array as parameters make sure the indexes related to the correct object in DB. like parameters: [1,2,3,4.....]

Comment: I just updated my doubt above and I have written that query but still its not removing the items from db